# What filter definition for MongoDb should I use in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

imagine this situation:

I have a entity called **Filter** with:

`string Text { get; set; }
 string State { get; set; }`

So in my Mongo collection I have this documents (filters):

```
{
"id" : "1",
"State" : "333",
"Text" : "SD"
},
{
"id" : "2",
"State" : "444",
"Text" : "X"
}
```

Now I have a service that it is supposed to return all the documents with the match of texts and states.

So imagine my service receives a `IEnumerable<string> texts` and  a `IEnumerable<string> states` with this values:

```
"states" : ["333","444"],
"texts" : ["SD"]
```

And the service should return `[]` because there aren't Filters with **state "333"** and **state "444"** with **text "SD"** at the same time. It only should return Results if my collection had this documents:

```
{
"id" : "1",
"State" : "333",
"Text" : "SD"
},
{
"id" : "2",
"State" : "444",
"Text" : "SD"
}
```

Then the response would be:

```
{
"id" : "1",
"State" : "333",
"Text" : "SD"
},
{
"id" : "2",
"State" : "444",
"Text" : "SD"
}
```

My actual code to create my Filter Definition for this situation is:

```
    private FilterDefinition<MyFilterEntity> CreateFilterForMyFilterEntity(IEnumerable<string> texts, IEnumerable<string> states)
    {
        var filterBuilder = Builders<MyFilterEntity>.Filter;
        var filter = filterBuilder.Empty;

        if (ListNotNullOrEmpty(texts))
        {
            filter = filter & filterBuilder.In(rf => rf.Text, texts);
        }

        if (ListNotNullOrEmpty(states))
        {
            filter = filter & filterBuilder.In(rf => rf.State, states);
        }

        return filter;
    }
```

But for my example case this code returns the response:

```
{
"id" : "1",
"State" : "333",
"Text" : "SD"
}
```

when it should be `[]` as I said before.

Is there a way to solve this situation? Thank you.

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0 with MongoDb.Driver 2.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a list of expected filters, then use `$or` query like below and before you return results you need to check whether length of expected filters has the same value as length of returned results.

In MongoShell your query could look like this:

```
db.Filter.find(
  {
     $or: [
       { State: "333", Text: "SD" },
       { State: "444", Text: "SD" }
     ]
   }
 )
```

And your C# logic could be like below:

```
var states = new[] { "333", "444" };
var texts = new[] { "SD" };
var expectedNumberOfResults = states.Length * texts.Length;

IEnumerable<FilterClass> result;
var filters = from state in states
              from text in texts
              select Builders<FilterClass>.Filter.Where(f => f.Text == text && f.State == state);

FilterDefinition<FilterClass> q = Builders<FilterClass>.Filter.Or(filters);

var query = collection.Find(q);

if(query.Count() == expectedNumberOfResults)
{
    result = query.ToList();
}
else
{
    result = Enumerable.Empty<FilterClass>();
}
```

Comment: That works on that particular case only, how can I do if I have more than 2 expected filters? Like this: "states" : [333,444,555,666] "texts" : ["SD" , "TT"] ?

Comment: @AndréAzevedo I assume that you expect 4*2 results or empty array in that case ? If that's true please check my updated answer

Comment: I will give you an image where there is some elaborated examples, please see this link and tell me if this is possible with your code: https://imgur.com/a/qhpfQ

Comment: @AndréAzevedo try my code, it should be working fine

Comment: I only can do it tomorrow and I will give you my feedback. I gave you my point and I will mark this answer as correct if it works!